# How to Find last x consecutive count based on a column

Tags: sql, vertica

**Column names**: `Site_key. Billing_date ,Reason_type`

**Things to Find:**

```
1.Consecutive count for last 5 months:
2.Last 3 month Count
3.Last 6 month Count
```

I have ro find Consecutive count for last 5 months for a site_key based on the condition Reason_TYpe.

`There are 4 distinct Reason_type: Zero_bill,Same_Units,Units_Deviate,Average_Bill`

I need to find for a particular site key say for ex: 3, billing_date is say 20-11-2015, and  reason type ='Zero_Bill'

1.How many consecutive previous scenarios were there were site had Zero_Bill (excluding current month)

2.How many such Scenarios in last 3 months (including current months)

3.How many such Scenarios in last 6 months (including current months)

**Sample data:**

```
site_key |    billing_date     | Reason_type 
----------+---------------------+---------------------
        3 | 2015-01-03 00:00:00 | AVERAGE_BILL
        3 | 2015-02-03 00:00:00 | ZERO_Bill  
        3 | 2015-03-01 00:00:00 | ZERO_Bill 
        3 | 2015-04-03 00:00:00 | AVERAGE_BILL
        3 | 2015-05-03 00:00:00 | AVERAGE_BILL
        3 | 2015-06-03 00:00:00 | ZERO_BILL
        3 | 2015-07-03 00:00:00 | ZERO_BILL
        3 | 2015-08-03 00:00:00 | AVERAGE_BILL
        3 | 2015-10-06 00:00:00 | ZERO_BILL
```

**Expected Output:**

```
site_key |    billing_date     | Reason_type          |LAST_Consecutive | Last_3_Months | Last_6_months
----------+---------------------+----------------------- +----------------+--------------------+--------------------
        3 | 2015-01-03 00:00:00 | AVERAGE_BILL|0|1|1
        3 | 2015-02-03 00:00:00 | ZERO_Bill         |0|1|1
        3 | 2015-03-01 00:00:00 | ZERO_Bill             |1|2|2  
        3 | 2015-04-03 00:00:00 | AVERAGE_BILL|0|2|2
        3 | 2015-05-03 00:00:00 | AVERAGE_BILL|1|2|2
        3 | 2015-06-03 00:00:00 | ZERO_BILL     |0|2|3
        3 | 2015-07-03 00:00:00 | ZERO_BILL     |1|2|4
        3 | 2015-08-03 00:00:00 | AVERAGE_BILL|0|1|3
        3 | 2015-10-06 00:00:00 | ZERO_BILL|0|3|3
```

**What I tried:
For Consecutive count:**

```
Select site_key,
       billing_date,
       Reason_type, 
       rank() over (partition by site_key,billing_date,reason_type order by         billing_date) as consecutive_count
      from indus_Dev_analytics.AVG_SCN  
where site_key=3 
order  by 1,2;
```

For Last_3_Months and Last_6_Months:

```
Select site_key,Billing_Date,Case when cnt>3 then 3 else cnt end as Count_OF_3, Case when cnt>6 then 6 else cnt end as Count_OF_6
from (
Select site_key,billing_date,Reason_TYPE,count(*) over (partition by site_key order by billing_date) as cnt from schema.AVG_SCN where reason_type='Zero_Bill' group by billing_date,site_key,Reason_TYPE
union all
Select site_key,billing_date,Reason_TYPE,count(*) over (partition by site_key order by billing_date) as cnt from Schema.AVG_SCN where reason_type='Average_Bill'  group by billing_date,site_key,Reason_TYPE
union all
Select site_key,billing_date,Reason_TYPE,count(*) over (partition by site_key order by billing_date) as cnt from schema.AVG_SCN where reason_type='Units_Deviate'  group by billing_date,site_key,Reason_TYPE
union all
Select site_key,billing_date,Reason_TYPE,count(*) over (partition by site_key order by billing_date) as cnt from schema.AVG_SCN where reason_type='Same_Units'  group by billing_date,site_key,Reason_TYPE) as a;
```

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?  Looks like either Oracle or SQL Server, but then again cannot be sure.

Comment: VERTICA is the database

Comment: This looks a lot like [this question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/121790/10769) ... related by chance?

Comment: Its almost same. I reposted it with detailed information. Can any one help me with this please?